# Mysql Covert rows to columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with order numbers, first name, last name, question and answers. There are 5 questions asked to the user, each answer to a question generates 1 row of data, which produces 5 rows per user. I need a query that returns order number, first name, last name and the questions and answers converted to columns, returning 1 row per user.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: This sounds like a horribly normalized database, with user data (first name/last name) in the same table as question data (question ID, answers).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to join the table to itself 5 times.

Something like

```
select q1.first_name, q1.last_name, max(q1.question), max(q1.answer), max(q2.question), max(q2.answer),max(q3.question), max(q3.answer),...
from questions q1 
join questions q2 on q1.first_name=q2.first_name and q1.last_name=q2.last_name 
join questions q3 on q1.first_name=q3.first_name and q1.last_name=q3.last_name 
where q1.order_number = 1 and q2.order_number = 2 and q3.order_number = 3 ...
group by q1.first_name, q1.last_name
```

Using max will collapse down the rows into unique first name/last name pairs.

Comment: I think I over simplified what I have. I actualy have is 4 table joined to get me results.

SELECT cart_survey.order_id, orders.ordName, orders.ordLastName, survey_questions.question, survey_answers.answer 
from cart_survey 
JOIN orders 
ON cart_survey.order_id=orders.ordID 
JOIN survey_answers 
ON survey_answers.id=cart_survey.answer_id 
JOIN survey_questions 
ON survey_questions.id=cart_survey.question_id 
Order by order_id